# After Insert Trigger and multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, multiple-records

These are my tables

```
CREATE TABLE Courses
(
   Course_ID INT IDENTITY  (100 , 10) NOT NULL , 
      CONSTRAINT PK_Courses PRIMARY KEY (Course_ID) 
   Catalog_Course_ID NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT FK_Catalog_Course_ID FOREIGN KEY (Course_Number_ID) REFERENCES Course_Catalog (Course_Number_ID) 
   Schedule_ID INT NOT NULL , 
      CONSTRAINT FK_Schedule_ID  FOREIGN KEY (Schedule_ID) REFERENCES Classs_Schedule(Schedule_ID)
   S_Date DATE NOT NULL , 
   E_Date DATE NOT NULL , 
)

CREATE TABLE Course_Management
(
   Number INT IDENTITNY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY '
   Course_ID INT NOT NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT FK_Course_ID FOREIGN KEY (Course_ID) REFERENCES  Courses (Course_ID)
   Course_Date_Meeting DATE NOT NULL,
   Duration INT NOT NULL ,
)
```

Now what I want to do is to insert data to `Courses` table, the `Course_Management` will hold all the meeting that happened or will happen in the course.

- `Schedule_ID` - which days the course have a meeting and also how many hours will be the meating.
- `Catalog_Course_ID`  can find the total hours of the course

So if I insert one course with `Course_Number_ID` (from catalog course table), `Schedule_ID` and `S.Date` (strat date) the trigger will find how many meetings we should do (by finding the course duration and divide it by meeting duration ) after  finding the all meetings, E.Date (end date) will be update as the last meeting that inserted.

I wrote this trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER CouseMetting
ON [dbo].[Courses] AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Course_ID INT --Last Course ID insert
  SET @Course_ID = (Select @@IDENTITY)

  DECLARE @CCID INT -- Course Catlog ID reference to CourseID last insert
  SET @CCID = (SELECT [Course_Number_ID] 
               FROM [dbo].[Courses] 
               WHERE [Course_ID] = @Course_ID)

  DECLARE @NUM INT -- Duration of the course in hours reference Course Catlog ID 
  SET @NUM = (select [Duration] 
              from [dbo].[Course_Catalog] where [Number_ID] = @CCID)

  DECLARE @MET INT -- Numbers of meeting 
  DECLARE @DUR INT -- Duration of 1 meeting 
  DECLARE @DATE DATE -- Start date of the CourseID

  SET @DATE = (SELECT [S_Date] 
               FROM [dbo].[Courses] 
               WHERE [Course_ID] = @Course_ID)

  DECLARE @Holiday varchar (24) -- Holiday in Israel
  DECLARE @DAY_NAME NVARCHAR(10) -- English day name
  DECLARE @Schedule_ID INT

  SET @Schedule_ID = (SELECT [Schedule_ID] 
                      FROM [dbo].[Courses] 
                      WHERE [Course_ID] = @Course_ID)
  SET @DUR = (SELECT [Meeting_Dur] 
              FROM [dbo].[Classs_Schedule] WHERE [Schedule_ID] = @Schedule_ID)
  SET @MET = @NUM/@dur

  While @MET > 0 
  Begin
     SET @Holiday = (SELECT  [HolidayISR] FROM [dbo].[FullDates] WHERE [Date] = @DATE)

     IF @Holiday IS NULL
     BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[Course_Management] ([Course_ID] , [Course_Date_Meeting] ,[Duration] )
            VALUES (@Course_ID ,  @DATE , @DUR )

            SET @met = @met - 1
     END

     SET @DAY_NAME = (SELECT [DayName] FROM [dbo].[FullDates]  WHERE  [Date] = @DATE)

     IF @Schedule_ID = 1
     BEGIN
            IF @DAY_NAME LIKE 'Sunday' 
            BEGIN 
                SET @DATE= DATEADD(DD , 2 , @DATE) 
            END
            ELSE SET @DATE= DATEADD(DD , 5 , @DATE)
            END

            IF @Schedule_ID = 2
            BEGIN
                IF @DAY_NAME LIKE 'Sunday'  
                BEGIN
                     SET @DATE= DATEADD(DD , 3 , @DATE)
                END
            ELSE SET @DATE = DATEADD(DD , 4 , @DATE)
            END

            IF @Schedule_ID = 3 
            BEGIN 
                IF @DAY_NAME LIKE 'Sunday' 
                BEGIN
                     SET @DATE= DATEADD(DD , 4 , @DATE)
                END
                ELSE SET @DATE = DATEADD(DD , 3 , @DATE)
            END

            IF @Schedule_ID = 4
            BEGIN 
               IF @DAY_NAME LIKE 'Sunday' 
               BEGIN
                   SET @DATE= DATEADD(DD , 2 , @DATE)
               END
               ELSE SET @DATE = DATEADD(DD , 5 , @DATE)
            END

            IF @Schedule_ID = 5
            BEGIN 
               IF @DAY_NAME LIKE 'Sunday'  
               BEGIN
                   SET @DATE= DATEADD(DD , 3 , @DATE)
               END
               ELSE SET @DATE = DATEADD(DD , 4 , @DATE)
            END

            IF @Schedule_ID = 6
            BEGIN 
            IF @DAY_NAME LIKE 'Sunday' 
            BEGIN 
            SET @DATE= DATEADD(DD , 4 , @DATE)
            END
            ELSE SET @DATE = DATEADD(DD , 3 , @DATE)
            END
            IF @Schedule_ID = 7 
            BEGIN 
            IF @DAY_NAME LIKE 'Monday' 
            BEGIN
            SET @DATE= DATEADD(DD , 2 , @DATE)
            END
            ELSE SET @DATE = DATEADD(DD , 5 , @DATE)
            END
            IF @Schedule_ID = 8 
            BEGIN 
            IF @DAY_NAME LIKE 'Monday' 
            BEGIN
            SET @DATE= DATEADD(DD , 3 , @DATE)
            END
            ELSE SET @DATE = DATEADD(DD , 4 , @DATE)
            END
            IF @Schedule_ID = 9 
            BEGIN 
            IF @DAY_NAME LIKE 'Monday' 
            BEGIN
            SET @DATE= DATEADD(DD , 2 , @DATE)
            END
            ELSE SET @DATE = DATEADD(DD , 5 , @DATE)
            END
            IF @Schedule_ID = 10
            BEGIN 
            IF @DAY_NAME LIKE 'Monday'
            BEGIN
            SET @DATE= DATEADD(DD , 3 , @DATE)
            END
            ELSE SET @DATE = DATEADD(DD , 4 , @DATE)
            END
            IF @Schedule_ID = 11
            BEGIN 
            IF @DAY_NAME LIKE 'Tuesday'  
            BEGIN
            SET @DATE= DATEADD(DD , 2 , @DATE)
            END
            ELSE SET @DATE = DATEADD(DD , 5 , @DATE)
            END
            IF @Schedule_ID = 12 
            BEGIN 
            IF @DAY_NAME LIKE 'Tuesday' 
            BEGIN
            SET @DATE= DATEADD(DD , 2 , @DATE)
            END
            ELSE SET @DATE = DATEADD(DD , 5 , @DATE)
            END


            END
            UPDATE [dbo].[Courses] 
            SET [E_Date] = (SELECT TOP 1 [Course_Date_Meeting] 
            FROM [dbo].[Course_Management]
            WHERE Course_ID = @Course_ID
            ORDER BY [Course_Date_Meeting] DESC )
            END
```

The `Fulldates` table is table the hold all the dates and holidays so if the meeting date is some holiday that trigger will now insert it and will continue to the next meeting

Now if I insert one course with `Course_Number_ID` (from catalog courses table) and a `Schedule_ID` and `S.Date`, every thing works fine.

When I try to insert multiple rows for the course table it works but for the `Course_Management` only the last row that has been inserted.

I got 5K rows table with Course_Number_ID , Schedule_ID , S.Date and I want to insert it.

I also tried to enter row by row with where clause and it's working.

So the only problem it with multiple rows.

Anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: First of all, for my taste, you're doing **way too much** in your trigger. The trigger should be very small and lean - **don't do** extensive computations in a trigger! Also: you're never referencing the `Inserted` pseudo table which is present in a trigger to hold the row(s) being inserted (or updated) - so basically you're operating on the **whole table** - which again will be a major performance killer!

Comment: I would also recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: First of all about the performance i dont really care basue it's goona be 1 time only, i mean ater i will insert the 5K rows or less i won't need that trigger anymore.

I tried to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() the trigger anit working at all even with 1 row.
about the update in the same table i trigger I'll change it.
do you have anther idea?

Comment: If you only need to do this operation once - then why even bother with a trigger? Just insert your rows into one table, and then into the other - and you're done .....